# c# - data from Woocommerce rest API

Tags: c#, api, rest, woocommerce

How to get data from WooCommerce rest API?

I want to pull product and all other data from a WooCommerce website to show in .net application

Comment: its unclear what you are trying to ask.. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please explain what you are trying to achieve more thoroughly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use WooComerce.NET plugin.

[Plugin Link](https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET)